# NuGet Restoration Never Works on Build Server

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a pretty simple application with some NuGet references and it works fine locally. I have  not committed the packages folder of course, just the config. When I have TeamCity build the solution, I originally got the error that I needed to enable Nuget Package Restore so I did.

Now when I build I get the message

> The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568.

Makes sense, but I get this error no matter how many times I build it. It continually fails. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe your TeamCity removes the solution before build then clone it abd starts the build?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989661/team-foundation-service-build-fails-on-nuget-package-restore

Answer (score 1):

Run the NuGet package restore before you build the solution.

Team City should have a NuGet Installer step which will restore the NuGet packages. Add this to your build steps before the compilation of the solution.

You an also do this yourself with a build step which runs:

```
NuGet.exe restore YourSolution.sln
```

However Team City's built in NuGet build step allows you to configure other things, such as private NuGet repository urls, easier than creating your own build step from scratch.